# Incrementar ponteiro dentro de lista ligada em C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Boas pessoal, teoricamente quando criamos um ponteiro e o fazemos apontar para um array,

```
int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int *p = a;
```

de seguida para incrementar o ponteiro para o próximo elemento fazemos algo como

```
*(a+i)
```

Mas quando se trata de uma lista ligada o meu código deixa de dar.
Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
typedef struct lista carroPiloto, *pCarroPiloto;
struct lista {
    piloto piloto;
    carro carro;
    int *tempo;
    pCarroPiloto prox;
};

struct corrida {
    int voltas;     // entre 5 e 10
    int comprimento;    // entre 500 e 1000 (metros)
    int n_carros;   // numero maximo de carros a participar
};

/* ------------------ */

int tempos[caract.n_carros][caract.voltas];
pCarroPiloto aux = NULL;

for(j = 0; j < caract.voltas; j++) {
     tempos[i][j] = calculaSegundos(idade,peso,exp,potencia,caract.comprimento);     // matriz dos tempos
     *(aux->tempo + j) = tempos[i][j];
}
```

E quando faço isto o ponteiro não vai guardando os valores. E não posso fazer

```
aux = aux->prox
```

porque assim avanço para o próximo nó e o meu objetivo é ter um ponteiro com vários tempos dentro de cada nó da lista ligada.

Comment: Existem várias informações em falta na pergunta, como a definição da matriz `tempos` da variavel `carat` e `aux`. Mas `*(a+i)` não incrementa o ponteiro `a`, simplesmente devolve o  valor que está numa determinada posição de memória a partir de `a`. Num exemplo concreto `*(a+3)` devolve o valor na terceira posição de memoria a partir de `a` considerando a aritmética de ponteiros apropriada para o tipo de `a`.

Comment: @Isac Editei o post com o resto das informações. Pois é isso, a minha dúvida é como é que faço o ponteiro `aux->tempo` apontar para o próximo elemento sempre que leio um valor da matriz `tempos[i][j]`

Comment: Sim exato. Faltava editar isso.

Comment: "como é que faço o ponteiro aux->tempo apontar para o próximo elemento" - Qual elemento ? O próximo da lista ou da matriz ? E se for da matriz qual em particular é o próximo ? O do mesmo carro na próxima volta ?

Comment: O meu objetivo é percorrer a matriz tempos e ir colocando em `aux->tempo` os valores que lê da matriz. Sim é do mesmo carro, mas da volta seguinte.

Comment: Então a ideia era colocar o `aux->tempo` a apontar para por exemplo o primeiro carro primeira volta, o `tempos[0][0]` e depois com ponteiros passar para o tempo da volta seguinte do mesmo carro o `tempos[0][1]` é isso ?

Comment: Sim era algo desse género. Tipo, quando `tempos[0][0]`, então o primeiro elemento para onde `aux->lista` aponta vai ser `tempos[0][0]` e assim sucessivamente. Quando termina o ciclo passa para o próximo piloto com `aux = aux->prox` e volta a fazer o mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) o meu objetivo é ter um ponteiro com vários tempos dentro de cada nó da lista ligada

Um ponteiro apenas ponta para uma zona de memória, o que lhe leva ao primeiro problema: Quem definiu essa zona de memória e lá colocou os valores ?

Aqui tem duas soluções:

- Ter um ponteiro para a matriz `tempos` já no elemento correto, sendo que cada vez que pretende navegar na matriz através do ponteiro tem de saber como o fazer.

  Neste cenário começaria por atribuir manualmente endereço do primeiro elemento da matriz apropriado ao piloto.

  ```
  pCarroPiloto aux = malloc(sizeof(carroPiloto));

  aux->tempo = &(tempos[0][0]); //primeiro piloto aponta para o [0][0]
  ```

  E isto coloca-lhe o ponteiro tempo a apontar para o endereço de `tempos[0][0]`. Com este ponteiro consegue sempre percorrer todos os elementos da matriz que interessam. Para percorrer necessita apenas de fazer o seguinte:

  ```
  int *tempo_corrente = aux->tempo; //declarar outro ponteiro que aponta para o inicio das voltas
  for(j = 0; j < caract.voltas; j++) {
      printf("%d\n", *tempo_corrente); //utilizar tempo corrente
      tempo_corrente = tempo_corrente + caract.voltas; //passar para o próximo com aritmética de ponteiro
  }
  ```

  Uma matriz é armazenada como uma zona contigua de memoria sendo cada linha armazenada uma a seguir à outra. Então para pegar num ponteiro e passar para a próxima linha da mesma matriz basta avançar a quantidade de elementos que existe numa linha, que no seu exemplo é `caract.voltas`.

  Note que não deve fazer `aux->tempo = aux->tempo + caract.voltas` senão perde a referência para o primeiro tempo daquele carro.
- Ter um ponteiro para uma zona de memória definida por si, e construída através de `malloc` no qual vai replicar os valores da matriz `tempos` nessa nova memória.

  Nesta solução o primeiro passo é alocar o espaço para as várias voltas do carro:

  ```
  pCarroPiloto aux = malloc(sizeof(carroPiloto));

  aux->tempo = malloc(sizeof(int) * caract.voltas);
  ```

  Agora pode percorrer a matriz `tempos` e guardar os valores que interessam:

  ```
  for(j = 0; j < caract.voltas; j++) {
      tempos[i][j] = calculaSegundos(idade,peso,exp,potencia,caract.comprimento);     
      aux->tempo[j] = tempos[i][j];
  }
  ```

  Mas e onde está a notação de ponteiro ?

  Bom você pode utilizar notação de ponteiro se quiser neste caso, mas é totalmente desnecessário e complica, mas ficaria igual ao que tem na pergunta:

  ```
  for(j = 0; j < caract.voltas; j++) {
      tempos[i][j] = calculaSegundos(idade,peso,exp,potencia,caract.comprimento);     
      *(aux->tempo + j) = tempos[i][j];
  }
  ```

  No entanto a maior diferença para o seu código dá-se no `malloc` que eu dei para o ponteiro `tempo`, pois se não o fizer está a tentar guardar elementos num ponteiro que não aponta para um local definido por si, e isso representa comportamento indefinido, e um potencial *segmentation fault*.

  O mesmo se pode dizer da variável `aux` que não pode ter acessos aos seus campos se estiver declarada como `NULL`.